# Turning two flash Android

Tags: android

I am trying to turn on both flash on Android device.

I have tried using:

```
backCamera = Camera.Open(0);
backCamera = Camera.Open(1);
```

but it threw error opening the second camera.

Also tried with Camera2 and SetTorchMode, but it raises an exception related to Max number of cameras in use.

There is any limitation on this with Android?
There is no way to turn on two flashlights at the same time?

Comment: what is your android device version?!(what is its api)

Comment: I am using Android 7.0 with API 24.